# JBossWS vs JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jbossws

This might be a trivial question, but it's been confusing me and I couldn't find a direct answer from google and through online searching.

What is the difference between JBossWS and JAX-WS?

Is JBossWS an implementation built on JAX-WS, so in a sense JBossWS contains JAX-WS? If so what makes people use JBossWS and not JAX-WS?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between JBossWS and JAX-WS?
>
> Is JBossWS an implementation built on JAX-WS, so in a sense JBossWS
>   contains JAX-WS?

JAX-WS is a specification for building web services in Java. It defines annotations to be used (@WebService, ...) and so on. The jdk contains a reference implementation of this specification, the JAX-WS RI.

JBossWS implements the JAX-WS specification. That is, it supports the same annotations and programming model as the JAX-WS RI. It does afaik not contain the RI, but provides its own implementation.

> If so what makes people use JBossWS and not JAX-WS?

No matter whether you are using JBossWS or the RI, you will be using JAX-WS. People will use an implementation different from the RI, because they need the support of additional WS-standards, such as WS-Security, WS-ReliableMessaging and more. The only additional standard the RI supports (apart from WSDL and SOAP of course) is WS-Addressing.

On that note: There are several more JAX-WS implementations with differing degree of support out there. For example Apache CXF or Metro.

Answer (score 1):

According to their web page (http://www.jboss.org/jbossws/) it seems that JBossWS is part of the JBoss application server, so it is a JAX-WS implementation.

Features:

- JAX-RPC and JAX-WS (2.2) support
- JBoss Application Server 5 (JavaEE 5 compliant) web service stack
- EJB 2.1, EJB3 and JSE endpoints
- Attachments Profile Version 1.0
- Support for MTOM/XOP and SwA-Ref
- WS-Security 1.0 for XML Encryption/Signature of the SOAP message
- WS-Addressing (W3C candidate release) and JSR-261
- WS-ReliableMessaging
- WS-Eventing
- WS-Policy